# Unable to login into IBM WebSphere admin console

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

[image: While starting the IBM Websphere server, I am getting this error]

I have configured IBM websphere. After the configuration is over, I am now unable to login into admin console. without admin console I am unable to start the server. So I get the above error while staring the server. Please help somebody.

Comment: It is a bit hard to tell exactly what went wrong based on the details in the question. One possible thing is that security was enabled but it fails for the user you are trying to log in with.
You should be able to start a server without doing it through an adminconsole with the startServer command, when it fails the way it does for you, you should check the server logs: startServer.log, SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log.

Comment: You should post the pertinent parts of startServer.log mentioned in console output.  Pursuant to the previous comment, I'm assuming you recently installed WebSphere Application Server (WAS) and are now trying to start it?  What version of WAS?  Did you run the Installation Verification Tool (IVT) after installation?  Did you enable security on the server when installing?  If so, you will need to include those credentials when starting the server from the commandline as parameters to startSever script.

Comment: what type of deployment are you using? standalone? is server1 the server you configured? are there others?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your setting are and why the server startup is failing. But you can follow below steps if you want to try to see if server will start after disabling security. Not sure if this will fix your server startup issue but worth a try if you suspect security related issue. If this does not fix the issue, you need to look closely at server startup errors.

To disable security, please perform the following steps via wsadmin:

```
<WAS_INSTALL_DIR>/bin/> wsadmin -conntype NONE
wsadmin> securityoff
wsadmin> exit
```

Restart the servers.
Connect to administrative console with security.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405302